# JQuery Mobile 1.3 Select menu dynamic refresh

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

Hi togehter i using JQM 1.3 and JQuery 1.9.1... i try to get a dynamic selectmenu working without a solution yet.

first i create a selectmenu with createDocument(div...) and .setAttribute(id,...) in the pagebeforeshow event. Then i used a lot of variations first line, second line and combined..

```
$("#select-keywords-list").selectmenu();
$("#select-keywords-list").selectmenu("refresh");
```

nothing worked yet for me..

after i added it i listen to it in the Domready($(#page).ready) function for a change event.
In the browser it works very well but on the phone i just cant get it to work. Hope someone can help me.

I also tried the native menu true and false..

thank you

mal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dEXac/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new select element    
    $('<select>').attr({'name':'select-choice-1','id':'select-choice-1','data-native-menu':'false'}).appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
    $('<option>').html('Select option!').appendTo('#select-choice-1');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'1'}).html('Value 1').appendTo('#select-choice-1');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'2'}).html('Value 2').appendTo('#select-choice-1');    
    // Enhance new select element
    $('select').selectmenu();

    $(document).on('change', '#select-choice-1', function(){    
        alert($(this).find("option:selected").text());
    });        
});
```

One more thing, don't use document ready with jQuery Mobile, they dont work correctly together. Instead use pageinit event. If you want to find more about it look here: **[jQuery Mobile: document ready vs page events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast response, i tried your code in my application... its not working not even in my browser, i develop a app with jqm and phonegap...

Comment: i try some more things out, and will write here if i find the problem

Comment: What browser are you using? This code was tested on desktop browsers, iPad and Android 4.1.1.

Comment: im using chrome v26 with ripple and the simulator, also have a android  4.1.1 device for testing..

Comment: and hook them at start $(":jqmData(role=page)").on(events, kernel);

   // rebind the events after is loaded 
   doc.bind('pageload', function(event, obj) {
    // ensure that events not double hooked
    $(":jqmData(role=page)").off(events).on(events, kernel);
   });

Comment: Why are you using pageload event? Pageload event is used only when you are loading page with load function. Correct page event would be pageinit, pageshow, pagebeforeshow....

Comment: i do listen to them var events = "pagebeforeshow pageshow pagechange click";... i listen only for pageload to prevent double hooking

Comment: here is the link http://therockncoder.blogspot.de/2013/02/jqm-skeleton-updated.html

Comment: I will need to check this implementation.

Comment: Can you post your whole block were you are trying to create select menu?

Comment: you figured out the Implementation ?

Comment: i got it working with $(id).selectmenu()  and $(id).selectmenu("refresh") ty for your help

Answer (score 0):

i know with a template engine its maybe easier but i tried this way

```
            function renderItemsKeywords(results) {
        var elementRoot = document.createDocumentFragment();
        var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
        elementDiv.setAttribute("data-role", "fieldcontain");

        var elementL = document.createElement("label");
        elementL.setAttribute("for", "select-keywords-list");
        elementL.setAttribute("class", "select");
        elementL.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Wähle Eintrag:"));

        var elementSel = document.createElement("select");
        elementSel.setAttribute("name", "select-keywords-list");
        elementSel.setAttribute("id", "select-keywords-list");
        elementSel.setAttribute("data-native-menu", "true");

        var elementOptD = document.createElement("option");
        elementOptD.setAttribute("data-placeholder", "true");
        elementOptD.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Wähle Eintrag"));          
        elementSel.appendChild(elementOptD);

        var allKeywords = $().checkKeywords(results);

        $.each(allKeywords, function(i, item) {
            var elementOptAll = document.createElement("option");
            elementOptAll.setAttribute("value", item);
            elementOptAll.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item));
            elementSel.appendChild(elementOptAll);
        });

        //alert(elementSel.length());

        elementDiv.appendChild(elementL);   
        elementDiv.appendChild(elementSel);

        var elementDivKey = document.createElement("div");
        elementDivKey.setAttribute("id", "keylist");

        elementRoot.appendChild(elementDiv);
        elementRoot.appendChild(elementDivKey);

        return elementRoot;
    };
```

than the other part

```
                           case 'keywords':

                html = renderItemsKeywords(itemData);

                $header.find("h1").html("Title");
                $content.html(html);
                $page.page();
                $footer.find(":jqmData(role=navbar)").navbar();
                $content.find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview();


                $("#select-keywords-list").selectmenu();
                $("#select-keywords-list").selectmenu("refresh");
                break;
            }
            $.mobile.changePage($(this));
```

hope you understand what im doing

Comment: the problem is that i got the selectmenu rendered in the right way, but if i click on the selectmenu it´s not gonne be opened.. if i use data-native-menu false its open but really buggy only if i hit 7/8 times...